# Connect Xp pro to samba domain controller

Tags: windows-xp, domain, samba, ubuntu-11.10

I was recently given the job of network and systems administrator. I was given the task of creating a server for our small office network. I went with ubuntu server 11.10 because of the cost factor. However I cannot find any tutorials on how to connect our xp pro boxes to the domain controller once I set up the server. Please help!

Since the inital post we updated to 12.04

Comment: You connect them to a samba domain controller the same way that you would a windows server domain controller - and there certainly are plenty of 'tutorials' on how to do that. Or are you saying that you've tried that and had an issue?

Comment: @DJPon3 Sorry no I hadn't thought of looking for that. I am new to linux period let alone setting up a server. What the boss needs he gets no matter how long it takes me to learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually what needs to be done is a domain change on the client machine.

Logon to the client as a local administrator account and right click on My Computer.
Click properties. Look for the computer name tab and click the change button near the bottom. Enter the domain name setup in your smb.conf file and then login at the popup screen using an account from your server with adequate permissions. Reboot your machine change the login point to the name of your network (under the options button for ctr+alt+delete login prompt) and login using any of your samba credentials.

Answer (score 1):

You have to write `net ads join -W testdomain -S win2003test -U administrator`. You can then write `wbinfo -u` to list the AD users.

It is all very documented [here](http://www.debian-administration.org/article/Using_Samba_on_Debian_Linux/print)

Dont forget you have to edit the `/etc/krb5.conf` first. Follow the link :)

Comment: what does this do exactly? This is clearly a terminal command but linux is way new to me. The file you linked to is a little beyond what I have learned

Comment: This in short joins Linux to the Windows domain, thus allowing users to access the samba shares. Once you join the Linux box to the windows domain make sure you can list all users (with wbinfo), then start configuring smb.conf to allow users to access the shares.

Comment: Thanks this helped me find http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8MWBhlaLIxQ Thanks!

Comment: No problem! Good luck. Click the tick if my answers has helped you :-)

Comment: My linux box was the pdc it didnt need to join the domain but your answer did help me find the above linked video!